# Make string centered in rectangle

Tags: java, swing

I have coordinates of rectangle to draw and I want to centre some text inside this rectangle.

```
int x, y, width, height;
String str = "This is a text";

x = 15;
y = 15;
width = 20;
heights = 30;

g.drawRect(x, y, width, height);
g.drawString(str, x + width/2, y + height/2);
```

Comment: Well that code does nothing because the width/height have a value of zero. so there is no rectangle to paint. Post a proper [mre] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Is it clear what the problem is now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to center the text then you need to know the length of the text so you know its width relative to the width of the rectangle. This is done by getting the `FontMetrics` instance from the Graphics object.

So the basic code would be:

```
FontMetrics fm = g.getFontMetrics();
int stringWidth = fm.getStringWidth(...);
int xDiff = (width - stringWidth) / 2;
g.drawString(str, x + xDiff, ...);
```

Of course you will also need to center based on the height.

Answer (score 0):

Doc says...

```
public abstract void drawString(String theString,
              int x,
              int y)
Renders the text of the specified iterator applying its attributes in accordance with the specification of the TextAttribute class.
The baseline of the leftmost character is at position (x, y) in this graphics context's coordinate system.
```

So... you are drawing your string starting at the center point of the rect but not the string.

`https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/FontMetrics.html` - get the font metrics from the gc and figure out how wide the string is.  Then subtract half of that from the start x.  Do something similar for y (remember that height doesn't start at base.)